# Evento onkeyup para hacer match entre palabras

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código:

Al realizar una búsqueda en "`buscaLugares`" , este me busca la palabra correspondiente perfectamente, pero solo si lo escribo correctamente.
Es decir si escribo "arena"<-- no me encuentra , pero si escribo "Arena"<-- si , quisiera saber o tener una idea de como poder lograr este `match`, sin importar si escribo en mayúscula o minúscula.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="buscaLugares" class="form-control" style="background:#5ba800;margin:5px" placeholder="Buscar Especialidad">
<ul class="classUl" id="GetbuscaLugares">
  <li>Arena</li>
  <li>Sol</li>
  <li>Playa</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $( function() {
        $( '#buscaLugares').keyup( function() {
            var bEspec = document.getElementById("buscaLugares").value;
            var matches = $( 'ul#GetbuscaLugares' ).find( 'li:contains('+ bEspec +') ' );
            $( 'li', 'ul#GetbuscaLugares' ).not( matches ).slideUp();
            matches.slideDown();    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes pasar la cadena al formato que tienen los `li` (primera letra mayuscula y lo demas minuscula): `bEspec.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + bEspec.toLowerCase().slice(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El siguiente código debería funcionar para ti:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){   
        $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){       
            var searchText = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
            $('.classUl > li').each(function(){
                var currentLiText = $(this).text().toUpperCase(),
                    showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
                $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Me comentas si todo bien.

Comment: Thanks eso funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Si no te importa tomar en cuenta mayúsculas y minísculas, ayúdate de:

1. [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf) y mejor buscar coincidencias de manera plena en cada elemento `li` de la lista. Yo modifiqué tu código afín de que vieras el resultado con lo que te menciono.
2. Además, ocupamos [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de jQuery el cual busca e itera los elementos que tengan una coincidencia entre sí (en este caso, hacemos un each a cada li de la lista `#GetbuscaLugares`.:

```js
$('#buscaLugares').keyup(function() {
  
  var busqueda = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase(),
      coincidencia = "";
      $("#GetbuscaLugares li").each(function() {
        var li_string = $(this).html().trim().toLowerCase();
        console.log(li_string);
        if (li_string.indexOf(busqueda)) {
          $(this).slideUp();
        }
        else {
          $(this).slideDown();
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="buscaLugares" class="form-control" style="background:#5ba800;margin:5px" placeholder="Buscar Especialidad">
<ul class="classUl" id="GetbuscaLugares">
  <li>Arena</li>
  <li>Sol</li>
  <li>Playa</li>
</ul>
```